# Program slow down when running on Visual Studio

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++

When I run my program inside Visual Studio 2012 it takes about 20 seconds to finish.

But when I run it outside VS2012 (directly clicking the executable) it only takes 3 seconds to complete.

Both builds are in release mode, so I don't understand why VS2012 is causing such slowdown...

Is this usual? or is there something wrong going on?

Also when I run it in VS2012 performance analysis it only takes 3 seconds.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: How do you run it F5 or ctrl+F5?

Comment: Can it be the case that even though the program was built in release mode, the debugger is still connected? Try `ctrl+F5` instead of `F5`.

Comment: That's right! (Turn that into an answer so I can mark it as correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a project under VS by either hitting `ctrl+F5` or just `F5`. The difference between the two is that the last attaches the debugger, so it'll run slower. Use `ctrl+F5` and you're done.

Comment: This doesn't actually explain _why_ running under the debugger is slower.  Launching from the debugger might cause one to expect a minor extra bit of work to launch the program, but it shouldn't actually impact the runtime speed much.  One possibility is that when launched from the debugger, you get the debug version of the heap instead of the regular version.  If the program does lots of dynamic allocation, then perhaps it's the debug heap that's the root cause of the slowdown.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Thanks for the comment. I admit the answer doesn't actually explain the *why*, although it solved his problem and I suppose that's what made him happy :)